# VBA equivalent of hasnext method?

Tags: vba, excel

Does VBA have an equivalent to the Java .hasnext method?

I'm trying to loop through a lot of sheets in an excel workbook and was going to use

```
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
```

within a loop, let me know any methods that would be more effective than this as I'm sure there are. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no equivalent, but most properties that support indexes have a `.Count` property that will tell you how many you need to iterate through

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this is to use the `For Each` looping method.

Here is a sample:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet

'- Begin looping through workbook
For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    '- Do code with each worksheet
    msgbox wks.name
next wks
```

In VBA this loops through the sheets within the `ActiveWorkbook` and allows you to reference the current sheet in the loop with the `wks` variable.

Comment: + 1 Looping is the way to go :)

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned above there is no equivalent of `.Hasnext`

You can loop through the worksheets using any loop. Here is a For Loop example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            '
            '~~> Your code here
            '
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

If I wanted to actually implement `Hasnext` kind of thing then I can do this as well

```
Sub Sample()
    If Hasnext(ActiveSheet.Index + 1) Then
        MsgBox Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Name
    End If
End Sub

Function Hasnext(numb As Long) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Sheets(numb)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then Hasnext= True
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a loop like `For Each x in Collection ... Next x`? It terminates automatically if the end of the list is reached.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to HasNext is checking to see if Next is "Nothing".

```
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ActiveSheet

If Not sh.Next Is Nothing Then
    Set sh = sh.Next
End If
```

But I agree with others that For Each..Next and avoiding Select and Activate is the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think VBA has a direct equivilent to hasnext. If you wanted to check to see if a collection has objects in it you could do something like`If colX.Count > 0 then...end if`

Answer (score 0):

All answers were helpful on this question.

I wanted to Show what I ended up doing and code is much more readable in an answer.

I just used the count method and looped until my iterator was equal to the count basically.

```
Sub Total_Sheet_Compiler()

    Dim sheetCount, i As Integer

    sheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    i = 1

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Do Until i = sheetCount

        ActiveSheet.Next.Select

        i = i + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest using @Gimp's method instead.  It does the same thing using For Each, which is a powerful way to work with objects.  Also, you should be aware that sheetCount is initialized as a Variant, not an Integer, in your code sample - `http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx`.  Scroll down to "Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement."

Comment: thanks for posting your answer. Yet, you should `Dim sheetCount As Integer, i As Integer` because VBA does not understand the syntax you used. Plus, you should try to avoid `Select` whenever it is possible.

Comment: VBA does understand 

"Dim sheetCount, i As Integer"

test it out for yourself

Comment: Also why avoid select? I assume this is another topic in of itself.

Comment: @MikeKellogg `Dim sheetCount, i As Integer` does not dimension `SheetCount` as an integer. `Select` is redundant 99.9% of the time so it bloats code run-time without any purpose.

Comment: @brettdj wow, this is news to me. If it doesn't dimension `SheetCount` as an integer then what is `SheetCount` ACTUALLY dimensioned as?

Comment: @MikeKellogg as per Doug's and JMax's comments as a variant - ie undimensioned.

Comment: @brettdj oh wow, I think this syntax `Dim sheetCount, i As Integer` works fine in VB but I guess not in VBA! Thanks for letting me know!